# How do I write a Dictionary to an array in a plist?

Tags: objective-c

I have a plist that is structured like this:

```
<dict>
<key>memos</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>First Memo</string>
        <key>content</key>
        <string>Testing one two three</string>
        <key>category</key>
        <string>testing</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>Test</string>
        <key>content</key>
        <string>This is a test memo.</string>
        <key>category</key>
        <string>testing</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
```

I'm reading it into an array like this:

```
self.memos = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Memos" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *tempArray = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"memos"];
for(id dict in tempArray) {
    NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *content = [dict objectForKey:@"content"];
    NSString *category = [dict objectForKey:@"category"];
    Memo *m = [[Memo alloc] initWithTitle:title content:content category:category];
    [self.memos addObject:m];
}
```

My question is: how do I add a new Memo (a dictionary of three strings) to the plist (specifically, the array of Memo dictionaries in my plist)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to grab the plist in a NSDictionary, then read the Memos array into a NSMutableArray, add a object to it, then save the mutable memos array as memos in the dictionary and write it back to the plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"memos"];
```

to

```
self.memos = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"memos"];
```

Hope it helps...

and make sure you write back the self.memos data back to the file.

Also note you cannot edit a file in the bundle. You need to ensure that you copy it over to the documents directory before you start editing it and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[tempArray addObject:NewDictionary That you want to insert];
```

then add this temp array to TempDictionary.

```
[tempDictionary setObject:tempArray forKey:@"memos"];
```

and then save tempdictionary to file.

```
[tempDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Hope it Helps!!